# anyone know where is the value came from?

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute

Anyone know where this value came from?
I have no idea why it is showing...

Please help

[image]

Comment: size is one type product attribute and he is the value in size

Comment: in the product attributes and label, I don't find where this +CS $5.00 came from

Comment: i think this is extra charge ...

Comment: is this value extra charged? As Mohit wrote, it is probably extra charge for this option